# Xpath with js and google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I have a code for generating xpath on click but i need to put that in an chrome extension. So how to do that?

Here is the code for generating xpath on click:

```
function get_XPath(elt)
         {var path = '';
          for (; elt && elt.nodeType==1; elt=elt.parentNode)
              {var idx=$(elt.parentNode).children(elt.tagName).index(elt)+1;
               idx>1 ? (idx='['+idx+']') : (idx='');
               path='/'+elt.tagName.toLowerCase()+idx+path;
              }
          return path;
         }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert(get_XPath(this));
    });
});​
```

also you will see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/CksqX/

How i can construct an chrome extension so when I click on some element on chrome current page to get xpath with my function in textfiled ?

How to pack this code to work as chrome extension?

Maybe the code is not very well but i will fix them, so i need to turn this into google chrome extension

sorry about trivial question,i'm new to web developing and sorry for my englsh

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what concrete part of this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html вщсyou don't understand so we can localize your problem